How can I assign custom names to sql query operators in Flink for Prometheus extraction?
I'm working with Apache Flink SQL and trying to extract operator metrics using Prometheus.
I have setup Prometheus metric reporter and I want to assign custom operator names to specific SQL operators (e.g., a JOIN operator, or an INSERT INTO operation) so that I can better identify and track their metrics in Prometheus.
For example consider the following snippet:
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT * 
FROM source_table
JOIN another_table ON source_table.id = another_table.id

As mentioned I’m using Prometheus as a metrics reporter in Flink (version 1.18). However, the operator names in the metrics that are produced by default from Flink in Prometheus (e.g., Calc_23, Join_16, etc.) are not very helpful or descriptive enough to monitor my app.
I tried using SQL hints like OPTIONS on the SQL query but did not make any difference.
Is it possible to assign custom operator names in Flink SQL queries to be reflected in Prometheus metrics and therefore have a better understanding of my app?
